# How can I get the array of Bluetooth devices around me using Browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, browser, bluetooth

I want to get a list of bluetooth devices around me. I use this code for this

"navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({acceptAllDevices: true})"

This block of code returns to me the devices around me and the received signals as a single object. There is no problem so far. But I want to get to the array of these devices.
Like This [Devices Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9aRC.png)

How can i get to that array with JavaScript? Is there a library you can recommend? It doesn't have to be JavaScript, you can suggest different programming languages or frameworks.
Thank You All!

Answer (score 0):

according to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Bluetooth) there are currently no way to get all the available devices around you

But you can use the [getDevices](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Bluetooth/getDevices) method to get the allready paired devices.

Comment: We examined the document you mentioned, but we could not get the sequence we wanted. The getDevices method is currently not supported by any browser unfortunately.